# Samba compressed transfer over network under Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, networking, samba, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ as a NAS, and the bottleneck is the 100Mb ethernet adapter I am using.

Is it possible to configure Samba to automatically and transparently compress/decompress files when they are sent/received over the network? This way I can get up to 380Mb transfer speeds rather than 100Mb.

If not, is there alternative that will do this, preferably with Windows 10/11 support?

*The USB 2.0 interface on the Pi 3 A+ has a max of 480Mb transfer speeds, and the ethernet interface and the storage disks are sharing this port.

Edit: The workload for the NAS is mostly going to be backing up disks with `cat /path/to/disk | gzip -9 > /path/to/share/backup.img.gz`** or a similar command.

**I know that this is a suboptimal backup scheme, but I'm using it anyway for now.

Comment: pi 3A+ is completely unsuitable if you want a performant NAS - with multiple disks plus ethernet all on the one USB 2.0 interface, you'll never get anything better than poor performance.

Comment: @Bravo It's what I had to spare, and I don't actually plan on hitting it hard anyway - mostly just WORM loads like maximally-compressed (compressed by the source PC rather than the target Pi NAS) disk image backups, so I don't need that much performance anyway. I'll look into better hardware, but I don't really have any other use for the Pi I'm using currently.